# Problemas al unir bases de datos de excel en Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

Estoy trabajando con bases de datos que juntas forman 1,781,654.
Para unir las 7 bases de datos estoy utilizando el siguiente codigo:

```
   for (x in Archivos_Potenciales) { 
  DATOS <- read.csv (paste0(Potenciales,"/",x))

 
  BasePoten <- rbind(BasePoten,DATOS)
 
}
```

El problema es que no me arroja todos los registros y quedan

```
 for (x in Archivos_Potenciales) { 
  DATOS <- read.csv (paste0(Potenciales,"/",x))
 
  BasePoten <- rbind(BasePoten,DATOS)
 
}
```

Cuando R termina de correr el codigo solo arroja 1,281,654 faltando registros. ¿Por que no arroja toda la información R?

Comment: Diego, por favor revisá la edición de tu pregunta, por que no se entiende muy bien.  Por otro lado, el código, más allá que no utilizaría un `rbind()` dentro de un ciclo, parece bien, o al menos no hay forma de detectar dónde podría haber una falla. Yo agregaría un print de control  con `nrow(DATOS)` este dato debería coincidir con las filas de cada excel y la suma de estos debiera ser el total final de filas en `BasePoten`

Comment: Hola Patricio, hago el ciclo con rbind() por que no encuentro otra forma de unir las 7 bases de datos, validando el nrow, sigue arrojando menos registros.

Comment: Diego, lo del rbind, es solo un comentario, es preferible "meter" cada df dentro de una lista y afuera del ciclo hacer `do.call(rbind, lista_de_df)`. Es un problema muy conocido de performance en R, el rbind dentro de un ciclo consume muchos recursos, por que todo el tiempo genera una copia nueva de los datos. Pero más allá de esto, lo que te digo, es que no veo nada raro en tu código, por lo que vas a tener que hacer un debug y ver dónde está el problema, lo del nrow es para que verifiques que el número de filas leído de cada archivo, se corresponda a las filas que tienes en la planilla.

Comment: Verifica antes que nada ¿Cuantas lineas tiene cada archivo? por ejemplo `length(readLines(file("nombre_del_archivo") ))`, esto con cada uno de los 7 archivos, suman más o menos el total que esperas? Si no lo hace, entonce faltan datos que estas esperando que existan, si suman más o menos el numero esperado, entonces el problema está en `read.csv()` por alguna razón no se leen la cantidad de filas esperadas, y ahí el `nrow()` por ciclo te dirá que archivo dió el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Buscando solución a este problema encontré la siguiente respuesta que me ha funcionado de maravilla, donde se cambia el rbind por fread, quedando de la siguiente forma la unión de las 7 bases de datos y en esta ocasión no faltaron registros

```
 for (x in Archivos_Potenciales) { DATOS <- read.csv (paste0(Potenciales,"/",x))BasePoten <- fread(BasePoten,DATOS)}
```